# Fail to obtain Sizeof Array

Tags: array

I have a nested array, but I get only the correct size of the first one.

I use this as a reference [Arduino sizeOf](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/sizeof/)

```
int clockOn_0 [] = {19,0,0};
int clockOn_1 [] = {20,0,0};

int clockOff_0[] = {6,0,0};
int clockOff_1[] = {22,0,0};

int clock_flag_0[] = {0};
int clock_flag_1[] = {0};

int *dailyTO0[] = {clockOn_0,clockOff_0, clock_flag_0};
int *dailyTO1[] = {clockOn_1,clockOff_1, clock_flag_1};
int **test[] = {dailyTO0,dailyTO1};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("\n");



  for (int m=0; m<sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);m++){
    for (int n=0; n<(sizeof(test[m])/sizeof(test[m][0]));n++){
      for (int i=0; i<(sizeof(test[m][n])/sizeof(test[m][n][0]));i++){
        Serial.println(test[m][n][i]);
      }
    }
  }


}
```

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

This is the result:

```
⸮Hpxy⸮ $08⸮x$:⸮⸮
23:29:40.059 -> 
23:29:40.059 -> 19
23:29:40.059 -> 20
```

Comment: sizeof(test[m]) is sizeof of the pointer. because you have an array of pointers, not an array of arrays. this is where array is not like pointer

Comment: but flag field consists only 1 item- I can’t use always with size of first element

Comment: the element is a pointer, not an array. (sorry, I edited the first comment, while you wrote yours)

Comment: In case of pointers- how can it be done?

Comment: you can use nested static initialized arrays like {{},{}}, or use defines or costants for the sizes

Comment: I think you are looking for a record, struct. Something like `struct clock_t { int on[3]; int off[3]; bool flag; };` and then a vector `clock_t clock[2] = { .... };`